# Return column 1 if column 2 has one missing match despite other matches

Tags: mysql

I hope this makes better sense when I show the table. I have a table like the below

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| machine1 | KB4534170 |
| machine1 | KB4534171 |
| machine1 | KB4534172 |
| machine2 | KB4534171 |
| machine2 | KB4534172 |
| machine3 | KB4534171 |

I want to search for KB4534170 and only return machine machine 2 and 3 where KB4534170 is not present at all. machine1 also have row where KB4534170 is not present so my search keeps returning machine1 as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select m1.* 
from mytable1 m1 
left join mytable1 m2 on m1.column1=m2.column1 
                     and m2.column2='KB4534170' 
where m2.column1 is null;
```

This will return:

```
+----------+-----------+
| column1  | column2   |
+----------+-----------+
| machine2 | KB4534171 |
| machine2 | KB4534172 |
| machine3 | KB4534171 |
+----------+-----------+
```

If you only want a list with `column1`, you can do:

```
select distinct m1.column1 
from mytable1 m1 
left join mytable1 m2 on m1.column1=m2.column1 
                     and m2.column2='KB4534170' 
where m2.column1 is null;
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you, but this isn’t quite what I want, close though. I only want machine 2 to appear once.

Comment: Did you check the last SQL statement (the one "If you only want a list with column1")?

Answer (score 0):

Also possible to do it as such:

```
SELECT column1 
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY column1
HAVING FIND_IN_SET('KB4534170',GROUP_CONCAT(column2))=0;
```

Basically `GROUP_CONCAT(column2)` will return something like this:

| column1 | GROUP_CONCAT(column2) |
| --- | --- |
| machine1 | KB4534170,KB4534171,KB4534172 |
| machine2 | KB4534171,KB4534172 |
| machine3 | KB4534171 |

Then we'll use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to lookup for `KB4534170`, which will return something like:

| column1 | GROUP_CONCAT(column2) | FIND_IN_SET('KB4534170',GROUP_CONCAT(column2)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| machine1 | KB4534170,KB4534171,KB4534172 | 1 |
| machine2 | KB4534171,KB4534172 | 0 |
| machine3 | KB4534171 | 0 |

Whereby `1` means that the value exists in the comma-separated `GROUP_CONCAT(column2)` result while `0` means otherwise.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ff8efe63cc95f130d1e2a0111d2b30e6)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your response. Both are perfect in there own way. I really appreciate it.